# List view for FastSearch result with xslt in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, xslt-list-view-web-part, fast-search

Can SharePoint FAST search result be populated in list view web part (document library list view web part) using xslt? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create custom code and extend the webpart for that. So, short answer is no, long is yes if you code it.